# Vary css element width dynamically

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following shortcodes in a page or post:

```
[custom_width width='500' color='red']

[custom_width width='600' color='blue']
```

The shortcode function is to display 2 buttons with their respective width. The problem is that the buttons are displayed the same width using the last width of 600.

The function:

```
<?php
    function xyz ($attr) {
        $xyzwidth = $attr['width'];
        $xyzcolor = $attr['color'];
        my_style($xyzcolor);
?>

    <style type="text/css">
        .mystyle {
            width: <?php echo $xyzwidth; ?>px;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="mystyle">
        My Text
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

note: the rest of the css is in its own .css file

```
function  my_style($xyzcolor) {
    switch ($xyzcolor) {
        case 'red': my_red();
            break;

        case 'blue': my_blue();
            break;
    }

<?php function my_red() { ?>
   <style type="text/css">
    .mystyle {
        ............
    }
    .mystyle: hover {
        ............
    }
    .mystyle a {
        ............
    }
    .mystyle a:hover {
        ............
    }
    </style>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: where is the code for the button?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the same class (`mystyle`) on both buttons, the last width defined on that class will apply to both elements.

For your purposes, you're probably better off with:

```
<?php
    function xyz ($attr) {
        $xyzwidth = $attr['width'];
?>

  <div style="width: <?php echo $xyzwidth; ?>px">
      My Text
  </div>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, that works. Problem is that there is more styling involved for which I called a function depending on style.

Comment: Then add the class, too. Use it for styles which are *common* to all the buttons (that's what classes are for), and add only the width (and other different styles) on the element itself.

Comment: I have edited the code and added more to it. As you can see the styling varies considerably which will make it very complex to added inline to the element as in <div style="width: <?php echo $xyzwidth; ?>px">
      My Text
  </div>

Comment: Then you'll need to use a different class each time, or add a unique id to each div, and style based on that. You *won't* get the same class to mean different things throughout your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Define your `blue` and `red` CSS in general. Not in your loop every time. Something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    // red
    .mystyle.red {
        ............
    }
    .mystyle.red:hover {
        ............
    }
    .mystyle.red a {
        ............
    }
    .mystyle.red a:hover {
        ............
    }

    // blue
    .mystyle.blue {
        ............
    }
    .mystyle.blue:hover {
        ............
    }
    .mystyle.blue a {
        ............
    }
    .mystyle.blue a:hover {
        ............
    }
</style>
```

And in your `xyz` function, give your div the desired class, and set the `width` of div internal:

```
<?php
    function xyz ($attr) {
        $xyzwidth = $attr['width'];
        $xyzcolor = $attr['color'];
        my_style($xyzcolor);
?>

    <div class="mystyle <?php echo $xyzcolor; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $xyzwidth; ?>px;">
        My Text
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```